# Menu link is not responding on mobile mode

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, responsive

I purchased an HTML5 responsive website template from a provider.

I deployed the template to our server to test the template.
Everything is OK on desktop mode, but on mobile mode, the menu links under the hamburger icon are not working at all. NO RESPONSE ON ANY CLICK.

Links outside the hamburger menu div are all working fine.

https://flyze201.com/academics
(You can test it here.)

I am working alone without designer. Please help me.

Comment: 2 Things, firstly I would never suggest buying a template for a website unless you are a developer yourself or have a designer, it causes problems long term and 2 the problem is in 'main.js' on line 298 onwards you have some code, that code (specifically e.preventDefault()) is stopping the links from working, i dont know why its setup that way but that is the problem

Comment: Pardon me, but you should really try to allocate the issue more precisely. You're actually asking SO members to fix your website/template. Please don't get me wrong – there are certainly challenges with your specific environment/setup. But you need to add more details.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the mobile menu working by changing the `<ul>` tags to `<div>` and `<li>` to `<span>`.  Don't know why it works but it does....and unfortunately without access to the actual code, it's a hard one to diagnose properly.  But, in a pinch this might work.  I took a screen recording...
[Screen Capture](https://streamable.com/p9b9ct)